# How to create username on master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to use a session variable with the username from a login to update lable at top it's master page. However, as I navigate from the login page the lable reset to the default. Can someone explain hot to keep it on the page. And if this method to display username is best?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? There could be a number of reasons the label is not persisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an actual `HttpContext.Current.Session` state variable to hold your username from the login, you have the ability to do what @woodykiddy suggests and have the master page's `Page_Load()` method in the code-behind set the `Text` property of the `Label` control to the session stored `string` variable that contains the username.

```
Label1.Text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session[YOUR_STORED_USERNAME_SESSION_KEY];
```

However, it is easier to place a small bit of server-side C# code in the `.aspx` markup of your `Site.Master` file. This can be done by wrapping the C# code in special tags like so:

```
<%:HttpContext.Current.Session[YOUR_STORED_USERNAME_SESSION_KEY]%>
```

This way, the server-side call to lookup your stored session state variable will be done every time the master page's markup is rendered and will always be current.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a label control like this `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />` on your master page.

So to display the username, you can use `User.Identity.Name` property to assign its value to the label control. Please be aware that an empty string will be return if the user is not authenticated. Also a good practice is to apply `IsAutheticated` check and perhaps display a different label text for anonymous users.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name; // username
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Guest User";
    }
}
```